# issue with mvn deploy:deploy-file : .jar not found

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jar

I am working on a Spring application split into microservices. My classes are in a separate module that I compiled with its pom.xml file in .jar.
The application is hosted in the cloud so I need to deploy my .jar in a repository of my application to then be used as a dependency. My jar file is first at the root of my project. I want my jar file with maven-metadata.xml files.
I have to deploy it in the app with the command line: mvn deploy: deploy-file.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:<the path of the folder where I want my deployment> -Dfile=<myfilejar-0.0.49.jar> -DgroupId=<mygroupId> -DartifactId=<myartifactId> -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=0.0.49 -DgeneratePom=false
```

But I have this :

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project C:\AppSpring\backoffice\myfilejar-0 not found.
```

Why does Maven not read my entire jar file?
Is my command line correct ?
Dfile should be the path like C:...\myfilejar-0.0.49.jar ?

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: IMO you should think about your architecture. Either use a Maven repository like Nexus or Artifactory to manage your jars (so no file deploys any more), or put all your projects as modules into a Maven multi-module project (so that everything is built together, i.e. also no separate file deploys). Deploying your own JARs with `deploy:deploy-file` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks. it's not my architecture, I'm just an intern with no manager to help me and I'm looking for a solution. The app is on heroku and it's different from my pc where the jar is a dependency. So I have to use a remote repository ?

Comment: But it would improve your working environment and makes your development easier...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution. I didn't think the terminal where to run the command could matter. I launched my command with comander instead of the IntelliJ terminal and finally it works. My terminal was blocking on the points of my files.

Comment: That sounds weird..